# Is fopen only for .txt extension possible?

Tags: c++, fopen, file-extension

I use fopen in my c++ code to open a textfile. But i found out, that this only works with .txt file extension, for example not with .pcap:

```
//this works
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "/sdcard/%s.txt", filename);
FILE* f = fopen(buf, "w");

//this not
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "/sdcard/%s.pcap", filename);
FILE* f = fopen(buf, "w");
```

with .pcap `f` is returning `NULL`.

Comment: "that this only works with .txt file extension" Nah, that's simply not true.

Comment: It works with any file extension.

Comment: Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the failing program and show us?A lso, for the failing program what is `filename` and what is its contents?

Comment: probably there is a problem with this file. Maybe you do not have enough rights.

Comment: Regarding the comment from @PeterJ about rights. Do file (with the `.pcap` extension) already *exist*? Do you have the needed access to overwrite it? Have you checked `errno` after the failed `fopen` call?

Comment: @Some programmer dude and if does not exist - if he has a right to create one. We do not know that system :)

Comment: @M. Zim try to run your program as root or administrator depending on the system. End check errno

Comment: Why is this flagged c++?  It's all C.   Try upgrading to fstream and you'll save yourself a load of pain soon.

Comment: What is buf? How big is it? If you had used C++  (std::string) instead of C you would not have to worry about that.

Comment: @UKMonkey The code is valid `C++` so it depends what compiler the OP is using. The tags should reflect that,

Answer (score 1):

> Is fopen only for .txt extension possible?

No there is no such limitation. You can open files regardless filename.

> with .pcap `f` is returning `NULL`.

It is `fopen` that returns null. You can use `errno` to see why. Check your system manual for what the error code means.

Comment: Downvoting as this offers nothing that isn't already asked in the comments

Comment: @UKMonkey What is wrong with duplicating information from the comments? Comments are not answers and this does answer the question doesn't it?